# Javascript Object Sorting by it's Index key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting, object

```
{
"1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Success"
},
"2": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Pending"
},
"3": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Failed"
},
"-1": {
    "id": "-1",
    "name": "All"
}}
```

This is My Object  i need to sorting by id value.

I am tried as follow to sort this object but it's not work.

```
status.sort(function (a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a.id) - parseFloat(b.id);});
```

how can i sort this object please give me solution.

Comment: You cannot sort the properties of an object.

Comment: `{}.sort()` = wrong, `[].sort()` = right. Use an array.

Comment: i can sort with index value..?

Comment: Again: You cannot sort an object. You can only sort arrays.

Comment: @Jyupin why do you need this for?